# Get single array element in a function return

Tags: php, arrays

If I have a function like this:

```
function getTotal() {
 $total = array("gcBalance" => 5, "gcTotal" => 10);
 return $total;
}
```

Is there a way I can call the function and get the `gcBalance` value out of the array without having to loop? Ideally it would work something like this, but it doesn't.

```
$balance = getTotal()[0];
echo $balance;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`echo $balance['gcBalance']` should do it.

Comment: Argh. I knew it was something simple; I've been staring at a huge chunk of code for way too long. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
$balance = getTotal();
echo $balance["gcBalance"];
```